# How to prevent mat-menu from overlapping the trigger?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use mat-menu with a trigger that is not at the very top of the viewport, but about 100px below. I've made a reproductive example for it.

Link to the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqgwro?file=src/app/menu-icons-example.html

As long as the menu content is small, everything works as expected:
[image]

But when the content is long enough to require scrolling, the trigger is overlapped:
[image]

How can I prevent this overlapping? Is it a bug in angular-material? I tried `[overlapTrigger]="false" [yPosition]="'below'"` but it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS class to the `mat-menu`

```
<mat-menu #modulesMenu="matMenu" class="some-class-name">
```

and afterwards use `::ng-deep` (even though they say it's deprecated) to set the `max-height`

```
::ng-deep .some-class-name {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

In your particular example add in the component decorator

```
styles: ['::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container .some-class-name { max-height: 300px;}']
```

Note 1: `::ng-deep .some-class-name` should be outside `:host`, in case you are using it.

Note 2: Regarding the deprecation state of `::ng-deep` there are several discussions about it and will not be removed soon.

Comment: That's a possible solution, thanks. However I wanted mat-menu to simply take all the available space from the trigger to the bottom of the page. I know I can play with `calc`, but maybe there is something better?

Comment: Oh, I got your point. I don't think you have a better solution. Angular material use `calc` to set the `max-height`, so there's no reason to avoid using it. Just write `::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container .some-class-name { max-height: calc(100vh - 96px); }`